# Transform to TB within a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column within my dataframe, df, that contains values in MB. I would like to convert this to TB

```
 type     size

 A        1,000,000
 B        80000
```

Desired outcome

```
 type     size

 A        1
 B        0.08
```

What I am doing

```
 1,000,000 MB are in 1 TB
    


 df.loc['size']=df.loc['size'].str.replace('\s\w+','').astype(float).div(100000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) like `df.loc['size']` it select index label, so is necessary omit it,because need select column, then replace `,` and divide by `1000000`, added one `0`:

```
df['size'] = df['size'].astype(str).str.replace(',','').astype(float).div(1000000)
print (df)
  type  size
0    A  1.00
1    B  0.08
```

If there are only numeric values:

```
df['size'] = df['size'].div(1000000)
```

Comment: This works! I kept getting a key error on my code. I will upvote in 10 min. Thank you-I seem to get this error: Can only use .str accessor with string values!  - Do I need to convert?

Comment: @Lynnette - If need replace `,` use `df['size'] = df['size'].astype(str).str.replace(',','').astype(float).div(1000000)`, else `df['size'] = df['size'].div(1000000)` working well